# Trend Micro Programmatically Scan File

Tags: deepsecurity

I need to run a virus scan on files uploaded to a server before storing that file.

Does Trend Micro provide a means to programmatically scan a file for virus in real time?

ClamAV provides a way for you to stream a file into it and it would scan that file for virus and give you a response in real time. I am wondering if Trend Micro has a similar interface?

I searched Google for a while and came up with nothing.

Comment: I am interested in this topic as well. Did you manage to find an answer? thanks

Comment: @costa I ended up using ClamAV because I could simply stream the file to ClamAV for a scan directly from my application while I keep the file in memory.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. Did you do research about other antivirus software? I found this site - it's very interesting: https://wiki.shadowserver.org/wiki/pmwiki.php/AV/Viruses (check out the links to the stats on the bottom left of the page). I was wondering if you chose clamav for the ability to interact with it programmatically, or perhaps you've done some additional research. Trend micro doesn't seem to allow for calls to its api directly (currently).

Comment: @costa The research and comparison I did at the time was Trend Micro vs ClamAV(business requirement). I went with ClamAV because it was free to use and offered the option to programmatically interact with the virus scanning engine so I am able to run ClamAV on the same box as the application and scan files before storing them.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the Deep Security Manager API does not support uploading a file for an immediate virus scan. I can't speak for what other Trend Micro products may offer.

P.S. I work for Trend Micro on Deep Security APIs

Comment: Hey, I have the same question as the OP. Does Trend Micro offer any programmatic interface that would allow a custom application to scan a specific file?

Comment: This may meet your needs, although I don't believe it is fully live yet: https://www.trendmicro.com/en_ca/business/products/hybrid-cloud/cloud-one-file-storage-security.html